# Who is Barclay, the supporter of monarchy, mentioned in John Locke's treatise of government?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, political-philosophy

In John Locke's [two treatises of government](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Two_Treatises_of_Government/Book_II#Chap._XIX._Of_the_Dissolution_of_Government.) he mentions "This is so evident, that Barclay himself, that great assertor of the power and sacredness of kings, is forced to confess" (chapter 19, paragraph 232). He then cites a passage from a book called "contra Monarchom.". I found many people called "Barclay", but I did not found any who fits the description and who wrote a book named like this.

Who is this Barclay, and where can this book be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[William Barclay (jurist)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Barclay_(jurist)): "his principal work was De Regno et Regali Potestate (1600)."

Also "De potestate papae: an & quatenus in reges & principes seculares jus & imperium habeat (published in 1609, after his death)."

"Adversus Monarchomacos": [De regno et regali potestate, adversus Buchananum, Brutum, Boucherium et reliquos Monarchomachos, libri sex](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_regno_et_regali_potestate).

And see [Monarchomachs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchomachs).

Comment: Thanks! I did not relate the book name to "contra Monarchom".